# Image slideshow with an infinite loop and a sprite

Tags: jquery, css, background-image, sprite, slideshow

I'm trying to make a small slideshow with one image (a sprite), set as a background. I move it's position so only part of it is visible, in a container that's specially made for it.

I'm using javascript/jQuery to move the position 107px (width of one image)
but if I use an infinite loop, my script just crashes.

Here's what I tried to run:

```
var slideshow = function (){
    var pos = 0;
    while(pos < 1000){
        $('aside.slideshow').css('background-position', '-' + pos + 'px 0').delay(2500);
        pos += 107;
        if(pos > 429){
            pos = 0;
        }
    }
};
$(document).ready( function() {
    slideshow();
});
```

Basically it should: shift the position of my image 107px to the left every 2500ms, showing the next image, located to the right of the previous image, and when it completely gets out of the visible area, it returns to the initial position and starts sliding to the left again.

How do I get (this script?) to do the above-mentioned all the time without crashing on page load?

EDIT: the entire idea is that the while never stops. It is basically a "while(true)" loop

Comment: have you considered CSS animation ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i commented and since this is somehing CSS can do for a while , i propose, **as a reminder & alternative**, that CSS animation could handle this:

```css
div {
  background: url(https://cdn.codeandweb.com/blog/2014/11/05/animate-sprites-in-css-with-texturepacker/capguy-walk.png);
  height: 320px;
  width: 190px;
  background-position: 0 0;
  animation: 2s walk steps(7, start);
  animation-iteration-count: 1000;
  float: left;
}
@keyframes walk {
  to {
    background-position: -1278px 0
  }
}
/* resize it ? */
div.bis {
  height: 160px;
  width: 85px;
  background-size: auto 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="slid"></div>
<div id="slid" class="bis"></div>
```

image from this tutorial pick up https://www.codeandweb.com/blog/2014/11/05/animate-sprites-in-css-with-texturepacker

my css a little different from link

Comment: This got the function I discribed done:
`aside.slideshow{
    height: 360px;
    width: 107px;
    background-image: url("../../images/TeamProject.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 107px 0;
    animation: 25s walk steps(5, start);
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes walk {
    to{
        background-position: -428px 0
    }
}`

Answer (score 0):

This is because every time the pos variable is greater than 429, it resets to 0, thus never being greater than 1000.

You need to change this.

Comment: The entire idea is it never reaches 1000

Comment: If it never reaches zero, then you will need to use setTimer as Chris' answer suggests.  Since it's an infinite loop, it will cause the browser to crash.

Answer (score 0):

How about instead of the while you just use a timeout?

```
var pos = 0;
setInterval(function(){
    $('aside.slideshow').css('background-position', '-' + pos + 'px 0');
    pos += 107;
    if(pos > 429) pos = 0;
}, 2500);
```

You can just kill the timeout once the pos reaches > 1000

Comment: Just one problem. Pos is never going to reach 1000, because it gets reset to 0 everytime it's greater than 429, and it always will, since pos is only incremented by 107 each time.

Comment: That is a valid point. He will just have to find another variable to determine when it is time to stop his movement.